# Extensions of symmetric unbounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I saw it claimed that every symmetric operator on a Hilbert space $H$ can be extended to a self-adjoint operator on some potentially larger space K. But I seem to be able to prove from this that every symmetric operator on $H$ has a self-adjoint extension on $H$ itself, which is not true in general. I cannot seem to find the error in my reasoning, which is as follows:

Let $A$ be a symmetric operator on $H$ with self-adjoint extension $B$ on $K$. Let $P$ be the projection valued measure witnessing the spectral theorem for $B$ and let $Q$ be the projection valued measure one gets by composing $P$ with the projection of $K$ onto $H$. Then it seems that the $\int_R tdQ$ is a self adjoint extension of $A$ on $H$.

Comment: Does "composing P with the projection of K onto H" result in a projection valued measure?

Comment: II believe so...I really mean restrict the original projections to H and then compose with the projection of K onto H.

Comment: The problem is exactly what Keith pointed out: $H$ won't be reducing for $B$, so $P_H$ and $P$ won't commute and then $P_HP(M)$ won't be a projection.

Comment: You can also try this out for the standard example $A=i d/dx$ on $L^2(0,\infty)$ on $D(A)=\{ f\in H^1 : f(0)=0 \}$. You can then take $B=id/dx$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, on the domain $D(B)=H^1$. Restricting this back to $L^2(0,\infty)$ won't work, because this subspace isn't reducing: elements from $D(B)$ won't stay in the domain when projected onto $L^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: To clarify:  if H is reducing for B, then the rest of my conclusion still holds, right?

Comment: @Isaac: Yes, but it won't be, for exactly this reason: your argument would show that $A$ had a self-adjoint extension after all.